# How to put a / in vaadin-date-picker

Tags: polymer, vaadin, polymer-3.x

I am using a vaadin-date-picker with polymer. I would like to put the right slash by default when the user types in a date in US format. So if the user types 01152019, it should auto format the date to 01/15/2019. Right now if I enter date without the / , it wont take recognize the value.

Answer (score -1):

You should set the `parseDate` method of the [`i18n` property](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-date-picker/html-api/elements/Vaadin.DatePickerElement#property-i18n) of your date picker so that it does what you want, for example, if you *only* wanted to accept date strings in US format but without slashes or hyphens you could do something like this:

```
const datePicker = something; // you probably did something like this.querySelector() to get it
datePicker.i18n = {
  // you can also set methods to format the date or the title and a few other things
  parseDate: dateString => {
    let month = parseInt(dateString.subString(0,2));
    let day = parseInt(dateString.subString(2,4));
    let year = parseInt(dateString.subString(4,8));
    return {day, month, year};
  }
};
```